# HTTP PUT with an array in parameters

Tags: http-post

I am trying to put an array (categories) in a http put url, but I always get an error. I can't find the correct syntax. I tried :

```
?name=test&categories=[1]
?name=test&categories=[{1}]
?name=test&array[categories]=1
```

...

Nothing works.

Is it possible to do it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your REST implementation.
Usually there are three ways:

- categories[]=1&categories[]=2&...
- categories=1,2,3,...
- categories=[1,2,3,...]

Better check your implementation documentation or debug your code if you can.